# How to fix this error: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String in react-native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

### How to fix this error: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String in react-native ?

I trying to store response of API in variable using AsyncStorage.
When i trying to setitem using setitem() of AsyncStorage. It give me successfully response.But when it called getitem() method. It give me below error.

So please help me how i can solved it.Thank you in advance.

[image]

This is some line of code of my file.

```
editedData=async () => {
        try {
            let getuserdata = await AsyncStorage.getItem('updateddata')
            console.log("get user updated data-->", getuserdata)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Something wrong--->",error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Typecasting is a programming fundamental. Research and understand it and your question will be answered.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RN docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage.html#content), you can only store strings with `setItem` in `AsyncStorage`

```
static setItem(key: string, value: string, callback?: ?(error: ?Error)
> => void)
```

You can use a third-party package though for a walkaround, like [this one](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage) for instance